# python regex to match file extension from compilation line

Tags: regex, python-3.x, parsing, compilation, file-extension

I have a compilation line the I'm trying to parse, all I'm trying to get is the full file name with the extension from the compilation line, but the compilation line can contain different file extension like '.c' or '.asm' or '.cpp' and of course the order of parameters can be different.
For example :

```
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c file1.c -o file1.o
```

or

```
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c file1.asm -o file1.o
```

or

```
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c file1.asm.c -o file1.asm.o
```

or

```
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -o file1.o -c file1.c
```

or

```
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -o file1.asm.o -c file1.asm.c
```

or

```
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c -o file1.asm.o file1.asm.c
```

The file names are sometimes enclosed with " for example :

```
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c "file1.c" -o "file1.o"
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c "file1.asm" -o file1.o"
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c "file1.asm.c" -o "file1.asm.o"
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -o "file1.o" -c "file1.c"
gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -o "file1.asm.o" -c "file1.asm.c"
```

I tried the following regular expression in python3 :

```
r'(?:\")?(\S+(?:\.cpp|\.cxx|\.cc|\.c|\.asm|\.s))(?:\")?'
```

and

```
r'(?:\")?(\S+(?:\.cpp|\.cxx|\.cc|\.c|\.asm|\.s)+)(?:\")?'
```

but I'm getting wrong results
for example for the last case I get :
file1.asm

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/mzho3T/1) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use capture groups to get the file name, and since you always know which flag precedes a file name (`-c` or `-o`), you can just get the whole word after it.

The regex is this one:

```
(?<!-o)\s"?([^-]+?\.[^\s"]+)
```

And you can use it in a script like so:

```py
import re

pattern = r'(?<!-o)\s"?([^-]+?\.[^\s"]+)'
matcher = re.compile(pattern)

matcher.findall("gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c file1.c -o file1.o")
# ['file1.c']

matcher.findall("gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c file1.asm -o file1.o")
# ['file1.asm']

matcher.findall("gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c file1.asm.c -o file1.asm.o")
# ['file1.asm.c']

matcher.findall("gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -o file1.o -c file1.c")
# ['file1.c']

matcher.findall("gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -o file1.asm.o -c file1.asm.c")
# ['file1.asm.c']

matcher.findall('gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -o "file1.asm.o" -c "file1.asm.c"')
# ['file1.asm.c']

matcher.findall('gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c -o file1.asm.o file1.asm.c')
# ['file1.asm.c']
```

Comment: what about this case : "gcc -DDEF_SOMETHING -g3 -Iinclude -Wall -c -o file1.asm.o file1.asm.c" which is also a valid compilation line ?

Comment: @sagi I edited my answer to solve this use case as well (:

Comment: thanks, but I want to capture only the source file, not the outcome object

Comment: @sagi Edited it again, added a negative lookbehind (`(?<!-o)`) which will throw out results preceded by `-o`

Comment: btw: you need to add escaping to ", it should be `\"`

Comment: @sagi I don't think so, because my strings are using `'` instead of `"`. If this answered your question please mark this as the solution and consider upvoting the answer (:

Comment: I had to escape them, look at my original regex in my question

Comment: @sagi Strange, my example runs as in the terminal so feel free to just copy and see if it works for you. I didn't need to escape anything, but if it works for you then great (:

Comment: thanks, it seems to do the job, just need to test it with more complex compile commands

Comment: @sagi feel free to comment here if you have any questions